# Get previous week value Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Date        Time    Quantity  
20171003    5:00           2       
20171003    5:15           5  
....
20171005    5:00           1   
20171005    5:15           9
```

I need to create a new column containing the quantity of the same day of the previous week, that is:

```
Date        Time    Quantity    Quantity-1
20171003    5:00           2         NaN
20171003    5:15           5         NaN
....
20171005    5:00           1           2
20171005    5:15           9           5
```

I figured out how to get the same day of the last week by using for example:

```
last_week = today() + relativedelta(weeks=-1, weekday= now.weekday())
```

How to apply this to my dataframe?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is collected in the exact same length everyday, using `pd.shift` as @EricB mentioned should be perfect.

Alternatively, you can create new dataframe and `merge` where days shift by 14 days and then merge back to original dataframe on column `date` and `time` (**note** assuming that you want the quantity at the same time on the next 14 days).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['20171003', '5:00', '2'], 
    ['20171003', '5:15', '5'],
    ['20171005', '5:00', '1'],
    ['20171005', '5:15', '9'], 
    ['20171019', '5:00', '8']], 
    columns=['date', 'time', 'quantity'])

df.loc[:, 'date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df2 = df[['date', 'time', 'quantity']]
df2.loc[:, 'date'] = df2.date + datetime.timedelta(weeks=2) # shift by 2 weeks
df_shift = df.merge(df2, on=['time', 'date'], how='left')
```

**Output** of `df_shift`

```
+-----------+----+----------+----------+
|       date|time|quantity_x|quantity_y|
+-----------+----+----------+----------+
|2017-10-03 |5:00|         2|          |
|2017-10-03 |5:15|         5|          |
|2017-10-05 |5:00|         1|          |
|2017-10-05 |5:15|         9|          |
|2017-10-19 |5:00|         8|         1|
+-----------+----+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Glad it helps @Batmax

Answer (score 3):

Does your index have a pattern? If yes, you could use `pd.shift()`. The `periods` paramater would be the number of periods in your `df`. For example, assuming your `Time` column is always whether `5:00` or `5:15`, and that you have calendar days, your `period` would be 7 * 2 = 14

```
df['Quantity-1'] = df['Quantity'].shift(14)
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @titipata solution, there is another way to do it without having to merge.

The approach in a nutshell goes as following

1. Get the datetime after 1 day/week/month from the first value
2. starting from that datetime onwards get the value 1 day/week/month before

so for example, if your dataset starts at 1/10/2021 00:00:00 (that's the 1st of October for you Americans)

#### First:

**you will have these values**

- 1 day after: 2/10/2021
- 1 week after: 8/10/2021
- 1 month after: 1/11/2021

#### Second Step

**get the following**

- Previous day values for values starting from 2/10/2021

And so on and so forth
Hope someone finds this helpful

```
from pandas import DateOffset
def add_past_values(df):
    df = df.set_index('datetime')
    firstvalue = df.index[0] 
    
#1. get the datetime after 1 day/week/month from the first value
secondday = firstvalue + DateOffset(days = 1)
secondweek = firstvalue + DateOffset(weeks = 1)
secondmonth = firstvalue + DateOffset(months = 1)

#2. starting from that datetime onwards get the value 1 day/week/month before
df.loc[secondday:,'lag_day_1'] = df.loc[df.loc[secondday:].index - DateOffset(days=1),'myvalue'].values
df.loc[secondweek:,'lag_week_1'] = df.loc[df.loc[secondweek:].index - DateOffset(weeks=1),'myvalue'].values
df.loc[secondmonth:,'lag_month_1'] = df.loc[df.loc[secondmonth:].index - DateOffset(months=1),'myvalue'].values

df = df.reset_index()
return df
```

Comment: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp', with the dataset from @titipata

Comment: @Yiffany from the error message, you're trying to compare a timestamp and string. This happens when you don't cast your values. After you read the dateframe use pandas.to_datetime to convert. For example if you have a column name `time` use `df['time'] = pd._to_datetime(df['time'])`